# I'm making a python tkinter IDE, and it keeps crashing when I have the user run the code. I'm using the subprocess module

Tags: python, function, tkinter, subprocess, ide

I don't know why but whenever I test my IDE app by writing code and running it, the IDE keeps on crashing/ saying not responding. I have really not much idea why, but I think it's because I'm using the `import subprocess` module. Please help me with this problem soon, I have to get this done soon. Thank you in advance!

```
def exec_code(event=""):
    
if root.title() == " PyEditor - The Best Beginner's IDE for Python":
    messagebox.showwarning(" Save File First", "Please save your file first.")    
else:    
 command = f"python {gpath}"
 root.update()
 process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
 root.update()

code_output, code_error = process.communicate()



Console.insert(1.0, code_output)


Console.insert(1.0, code_error)
```

Comment: `process.communicate()` waits for the process to end. While it's waiting `tkinter` can't update itself so it becomes unresponsive. Look at `subprocess.Popen`'s documentation. I think it would be better if you just used a `tkinter` loop to wait until `process.poll()` isn't `None` (the process finishes)